# undefined number return in recursive loop javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, recursion

i am trying to loop through 15 string list and want to bind random value to another list.

i am also using one more list to check used number in that random numbers.
i am facing problem in this recursive loop and random number. why it is creating undefined value sometimes?

**please help me in this and yes i checked every other option from last one day this is not repeated or duplicate question. so please check below code before down voting this question.**

codepen is here
    http://codepen.io/anon/pen/CaAfi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is with this branch here:

```
if (randnum == -1 || randnum == undefined) {
    randnum = CheckRandomNum(iconListLength, usedNumLst);
} else {
    usedIconList.push(iconList[randnum]);
    usedNumLst.push(randnum);
}
```

If `randnum` is `undefined`, you call `CheckRandomNum`, but you continue the loop (so instead of 15 items in your `usedIconList`, you have n-less items. If you update your logic to address the iteration issue, the code no longer produces undefined items.

Here's an updated codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qymsK

The only thing I changed was adding `--j` to perform the loop again:

```
if (randnum == -1 || randnum == undefined) {
    --j;
    randnum = CheckRandomNum(iconListLength, usedNumLst);
} else {
    usedIconList.push(iconList[randnum]);
    usedNumLst.push(randnum);
}
```

Comment: thanks buddy. i am very very thankful to you. sometime we did small mistake and face problem for so many long days.